# Собственный gui

Tags: gui, java, swing

Извиняюсь за столь глупый вопрос, но только начал постигать java, интересует следующее: как или с помощью чего реализуют собственные пользовательские интерфейсы? Например, я не желаю использовать готовую swing'овскую JButton, а хочу вставить собственноручно нарисованную. У меня в голове только одна мысль, это переписывать стандартные swing классы под свой лад, с добавлением своих изображений...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Напишите свой класс:

```
public class MyJButton extends JButton
```

и изгаляйтесь скока душе угодно, лепите треугольные, серо-буро малиновые кнопки и проч. На то и ООП!

Comment: Метод paint

Comment: Так я предполагал, просто думал может я не прав и делаю все через пятую точку) Всем спасибо, вопрос исчерпан.

Comment: можно по простому и грубо - сверху батона ставить рисунок, форма всегда будет - прямоугольник, зато кастомный =)

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте посмотреть в сторону JavaFX. тут неплохо реализована кастомизация элементов через CSS